# Concerete examples of physical systems that can be (approximately) modelled using a 2D triharmonic equation?

Tags: waves, differential-equations, non-linear-systems, linear-systems

I have some experimental measurements of input-driven standing-wave resonances in a nonlinear, 2D medium. I think it's fair to assume that the dynamics are homogeneous and isotropic, and we can think of these data as coming from a circular domain with the boundary clamped to 0 (Dirichlet boundary conditions).

### A putative phenomenological description of the data as a linear PDE

I figured that, whatever physics is *actually* happening, it can probably be approximated via a linear PDE. This could emerge as the linearized picture of some nonlinear dynamics near a stable fixed point, or it could simply reflect some global dynamics that are well approximated as effectively linear in the dynamical range measured in the data.
For sake of argument, I decided to explore damped wave equations for $u(x,t)$ of the form:

$$
\ddot u = -c(-\Delta)^a u - 2d \dot u,\qquad c,a,d>0,
$$

where $\Delta = \nabla^2$ is the Laplacian. In the Laplace ($s$) *time* domain, we have

$$
[s^2 + 2ds + c(-\Delta)^a ] \hat u = 0
$$

Let's further switch to the eigenbasis of the (negative) Laplacian ($-\Delta$) operator, with $\eta$ denoting the eigenvalues of $-\nabla^2$ (i.e. the negatives of the Laplacian eigenvalues; $\eta\ge 0$). We have:

$$
[s^2 + 2ds + c\eta^a ] \tilde u = 0
$$

I'd like to match the dispersion relation in the data, so I'll solve for $s$ in terms of $\eta$.
Solving the quadratic for $s$ in terms of $\eta$ yields:

$$
s = 
-d \pm \sqrt{d^2 - c\eta^a}
$$

Now, I'm interested in wave solutions; These are when $s = \rho \pm i\omega$ is complex, i.e. $d^2-c\eta^a<0$. For these solutions, we have oscillation frequency $\omega$ related to the negative Laplacian eigenvalue $\eta$ as :

$$
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\omega^2 = c\eta^a - d^2
\end{aligned}
\label{dispersion}
\tag{1}
\end{equation}
$$

#### Regressing to data

I regressed the dispersion relation $\eqref{dispersion}$ to the data (resonant peaks extracted by fitting a Lortenzian function to power spectrum peaks), and found $a=3$, which confused me.

I'd hoped the linearized dynamics might resemble d'Alembert waves $\ddot u \propto \Delta u$ or Euler-Bernoulli bending-mode waves $\ddot u \propto - \Delta^2 u$.
If I'd gotten either $a=1$ or $a=2$, I'd have a picture of springs and masses in my head, and I'd start mediating about whether this seems like a sensible approximation for some nonliner model.
Instead I have this:

$$
\ddot u \approx c \Delta^3 u - 2d\dot u
$$

### Disclaimer

Some of you will probably say "this is *not* how you do physics!". This is true, but bear with me. Intuition from linear PDEs that superficially resemble the data can provide helpful intuition when searching the space of nonlinear models. Experiments can then help disambiguate the top candidates. Descriptions in terms of polynomials in the Laplacian should resemble the Taylor expansion of the true spatial operator around zero spatial frequency. Or, maybe observing $a=3$ is a hint that I want to consider some time derivatives higher than order two. Things such as this. Vague intuition about what sort of things could be pushing and pulling to give rise to such a dispersion relation are helpful.

So, noting that $\eta = \|\nu\|^2$ where $\|\nu\|$ is the length of the 2D spatial Fourier component in $\eqref{dispersion}$, has anyone ever seen a dispersion relation like

$$
\omega^2 = c \|\nu\|^6 - d^2
$$

before?

Comment: Thanks! I should have added "I'm not a physicist". To me it seemed to make sense to assume the resonances are standing waves, induced purely by the boundary conditions, and to ask what wave equation could lead to this. The boundary seems to go to zero amplitude for the state variable we're measuring, but *who knows* what's actually happening. (Sorry for not being concrete, I don't want to disclose unpublished results from my experimental collaborators).

Comment: I also deleted the bit where I can only see something that looks like 1s, 2p, 3d, and 2s modes in that order. The experiment didn't/couldn't probe frequencies beyond this and/or there is a cutoff where travelling waves decay too quickly for any higher-frequency modes, and therefore don't excite the system very much and can't propagate far enough to interfere with themselves to make a standing wave. Which is to say: I wouldn't dare try *anything* asymptotic here :P

Comment: I guess I can add that we know that the system is classical (nothing exotic!), and the observed phenomena are almost surely mediated by coupling that is not global (and mediated by interactions that would support traveling waves, if not for the boundary). The coupling might not be *strictly* local. Maybe instead of a polynomial in the Laplacian, we have integral coupling in the form of a convoltion kernel. I had sort of hoped this might not matter, since a polynomial in the Laplacian is just a low-order approximation of any nice coupling kernel via a Taylor expansion at zero frequency.

Comment: I mean, yes, five. It's embarrassing. But, hear me out! If you saw five resonance peaks that *perfectly* matched the d'Alembert wave equation, you'd probably say "okay, whatever is *actually* happening here, probably a linear wave equation captures the coarse phenomenology, and all models should be consistent with this". So, it's not that crazy. I suppose the problem creeps in when that *doesn't* work. There aren't really enough data to constrain anything more sophisticated.

Comment: I'm not really looking for a "true" physics model, but the sort of "next leading order" flavour of the "does it fit a d'Alembert wave equation?" reasoning. The idea is not to get the *actual* model, but to get some of intuition that constrains the type of relationships you can expect in *any* model, if all you can do is measure the first 5 frequencies. My argument for "if you saw $a=1$, you'd probably be convinced that it has to be a model that looks like linear, classical waves, to first order, at low frequencies" makes me feel like we're not completely lost here. Just, very data-poor.

Comment: I'm using the terms in the general sense that one sometimes sees when discussing 2D circular membranes. So, 1s has no angular nodes, and one radial node at the putative boundary. 2s has one radial node, no angular nodes. 2p has one angular node and single radial node at the boundary. 3d has two angular nodes and one radial node at the boundary.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146485/discussion-between-lpz-and-mrule).